# Div with width set to 1280 is displaying at 1600 width in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a div I'm using for a background, with a set width and height.  The dimensions are `1280x960`, for the div and for the image used.  But in Firefox or IE, the div has a width of `1600`.  I've tried adding a max-width, setting the padding to 0, I even double-checked to make sure my browser window wasn't zoomed in.  I didn't think I needed to do any `-webkit-moz-` additions for something like width and height, but Chrome is the only one of the major three that is displaying it how I intended.

My code:

```
<style>
#background
{
    width: 1280px;
    max-width: 1280px;
    height: 960px;
    background-image: url("img/background.png");
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i see nothing wrong, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOoWMq .

Comment: Your code is showing me a 1600 px wide image as well. :(

Comment: Are you sure you are not using any plugin for FF or maybe the viewport is zoomed in?

Answer (score 0):

This way may help you

```
#background { 
   width: expression( document.body.clientWidth > 1279 ? "1280px" : "auto" ); 
   /* sets max-width for IE */
}

#background { 
   max-width: 1280px; 
   /* this sets the max-width value for all standards-compliant browsers */
}
```

Comment: IE supports `max-width` since version 7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `background-repeat: no-repeat;` for the background img and also `background-size:cover;`

```
#background  {
    width: 1280px;
    height:960px;
    max-width: 1280px;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1280x960");
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**DEMO**  http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/mLxn46kj/5/

Comment: How is the background related to the width?

Comment: I know what you mean, but i did not see anything wrong in the code. Maybe it was smt she had cached on Firefox, or smt else in the code which was breaking. That's what happens when the code shown is only few lines and not a jsfiddle with the whole code.

Comment: This code was provided by another user and is having the same problem:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOoWMq